# Adding median line to boxplot

Tags: plot, box

I have created box plot using seaborn in python but not sure how to put the median line accross the plot.
Can anyone help me in creating the median line in this box plot?

Answer (score 0):

[Box plot is attached for review.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCYuD.png)